# Перегрузка дружественной функции

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов, дружественная-функция

Задание: Создать класс целых чисел Integer. Определить перегруженную функцию, воз-вращающую максимальное из двух аргументов. Функция не является членом класса целых чисел. Перегруженные функции имеют аргументы типа int, double, Integer. Тело перегруженных функций должны быть одинаковыми.

Код я написал, он работает. Но сомневаюсь, что правильно реализовал перегрузку дружественных функций. Все ли я правильно сделал?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Integer
{
private:
    double a, b;
public:
    Integer();
    ~Integer();
    void input();
    void output();
    friend int max(int a, double b);
    friend int max(int a, double b, Integer c); 
};

Integer::Integer()
{
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    cout << "Constructor works" << endl;
}

Integer::~Integer()
{
    cout << "Destructor works" << endl;
    a = NULL;
    b = NULL;
}

void Integer::input()
{
    cout << "Input two elements: " << endl;;
    cin >> a >> b;
}

void Integer::output()
{
    cout << "The largest number is " << max(a,b)<<endl;
}

int max(int a, double b)
{
    if (a > b) {
        cout << "The first number is larger than the second" << endl;
        return a;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The second number is larger than the first" << endl;
        return b;
    }
}

int max(int a, double b, Integer c)
{
    if (a > b) {
        cout << "The first number is larger than the second" << endl;
        return a;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The second number is larger than the first" << endl;
        return b;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Integer c;
    char p='y';
    while (p=='y'||p=='Y')
    {
        c.input();
        c.output(); 
        cout << "Want to continue? y/n" << endl;
        p = _getch();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы считаете, что это -

```
class Integer
{
private:
    double a, b;
```

объявление класса **ЦЕЛЫХ** чисел?

Как я понимаю, от вас требуется создать класс, в котором хранится целочисленное значение. Типа

```
class Integer
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    Integer(int i);

    ...

    int value() const;

    // Прочий функционал
```

После этого все, что вам нужно - это написать

```
int maximum(int a, int b)       { return (a>b) ? a : b; }
int maximum(double a, double b) { return (a>b) ? a : b; }

Integer maximum(const Integer& a, const Integer& b)
{
    return Integer(maximum(a.value(),b.value()));    
}
```

Где-то так...

Comment: Спасибо. А можно поподробнее с функцией  int value() const ?

Comment: Ну просто она возвращает хранящееся в классе значение. В простейшем случае - это самое `a`, которое в классе объявлено..

Comment: а как выглядит тело этой самой функции?

Comment: ??? Я же написал - *возвращает хранящееся в классе значение*. Простите... этот код, что в начале вопроса - точно вы сами писали?